# Is it safe to perform ETH transfers within a library

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks

Would it be safe to perform ETH transfers in a linked library instead of within the original contract to save contract size?

Also, if the low level call to the receiver from the library triggers the receiver’s fallback, would the receiver then be able to perform a reentrancy attack through the library and deplete the original contracts funds?

I am asking this since I can’t find any protocol performing ETH transfers within libraries.